# Sqlite3 getting ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.0.4. This error was happening more but I upgraded from 4.0.1.

We are using sqlite3 in production (something I didn't even realize). I have created a postgres DB before, I suppose we can switch over to postgres, if that seems like it could be the problem. What could it be? [if it is bc sqlite, is there an easy way to convert past data to sqlite data?]

```
2014-05-29T17:46:29.300034+00:00 app[web.2]: ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.003 seconds)):
```

http://pastebin.com/8pZKvpUk

```
production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I just noticed this in the Gemfile

```
gem 'sqlite3', :group => [:development, :test]
gem 'pg', :group => [:production]
```

Does this mean we are using pg for production even though the yml saved is as .sqlite3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku doesn't allow the use of sqlite3 in production.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

You will have to switch to PG.

Check your database connection with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
```

And the adapter used:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name
```

Comment: is there a way to make sure I am not running PG in production? @Jorge de los Santos

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/connection

Here you have the info of the connection of active record.